# operand comparison in Zend Framework source code

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've been looking through Zend Framework's source code and noticed that most (if not all) comparisons are done with the operands in the reverse order I would expect:

```
if ((false !== $request) {
    ...
}
```

instead of:

```
if (($request !== false) {
    ...
}
```

What is the reason for this convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [`Left-Hand Comparison`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions#Left-hand_comparisons).

Basically, it's so that if you forget to put the second `=` in `==`, it'll error rather change the value of the variable...

Answer (score 3):

```
if (false = $request)
```

will fail quickly (if you meant `false == true` for example) - you can't assign to a constant. It's one of those tips that you figure out, or see and follow, to help catch problems.  The ZF convention of leaving off a close-PHP tag (`?>`)  at the ned of a file is the same idea. You can't have whitespace that might be output an cause a problem, if there's no tag for it to follow.